# The GridDB Go client is not letting me build my project

Tags: database, go, nosql, iot, in-memory

I'm trying to test the GridDB Go client with just a simple creation of a users container on my test website. My issue is I keep getting the following error:

```
main.go:28:2: no Go files in /home/gopheritis/go/src/github.com/griddb/go_client
```

Here's my Go env... everything is normal and works:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/gopheritis/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/gopheritis/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/gopheritis/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build238154447=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I was following along with the instructions and they mentioned running

```
export GODEBUG=cgocheck=0
```

which I already did. I'm obviously missing something else, but what can it be?

Comment: That project doesn't work like a normal Go package, and requires adding another directory to `GOPATH`, which it doesn't look like you've done. Also, I would tend to avoid packages that require `cgocheck=0` in production.

Comment: @JimB Thank you. This was it. I was able to work around it by putting the Go Client in another directory and adding that directory into my Go PATH